# Xpath select tr tags that do not contain nested tr tags

Tags: html, xpath

Please help me find an xpath expression to select only those tr in which there are no nested tr and table tags.

I tried using this expression //table//tr[not(.//table)], but this way I only skip the lines that contain the table tag. I also need to skip those in the <caption... tag. [xpather](http://xpather.com/vMa8mnUc)

For example, this block should be skipped:

```html
<tr><td>UL approval</td>
  <td><table><caption></caption><colgroup class='pd-table-cols-2'><col class='pd-table-col-1'><col class='pd-table-col-2'></colgroup><tbody>
    <tr><td>Ta</td><td>-25...70 °C</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Enclosure type</td><td>Type 1 </td></tr>
    <tr><td>voltage supply</td><td>Limited Voltage/Current </td></tr>
    <tr><td>UL approval number</td><td>A005 </td></tr>
    <tr><td>File number UL</td><td>E174191 </td></tr></tbody>
  </table></td></tr>
```

```html
<tbody>
<tr><td>Electrical design</td><td>PNP</td></tr>
<tr><td>Output function</td><td>normally open</td></tr>
<tr><td>Housing</td><td>Threaded type</td></tr>
<tr><td>Correction factor</td><td>steel: 1 / stainless steel: 1 / brass: 1 / aluminum: 1 / copper: 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hysteresis [% of Sr]</td><td>3...15</td></tr>
<tr><td>Vibration resistance</td><td><table><caption></caption><colgroup class='pd-table-cols-2'><col class='pd-table-col-1'><col class='pd-table-col-2'></colgroup><tbody>
<tr><td>EN 60068-2-6 Fc</td><td>20 g (10...3000 Hz) / 50 sweep cycles per frequency, 1 octave per minute in 3 axes</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>
<tr><td>Shock resistance</td><td><table><caption></caption><colgroup class='pd-table-cols-2'><col class='pd-table-col-1'><col class='pd-table-col-2'></colgroup><tbody>
<tr><td>EN 60068-2-27 Ea</td><td>100 g 11 ms half-sine, 3 shocks each in every direction of the 3 coordinate axes</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>
<tr><td>Continuous shock resistance</td><td><table><caption></caption><colgroup class='pd-table-cols-2'><col class='pd-table-col-1'><col class='pd-table-col-2'></colgroup><tbody>
<tr><td>EN 60068-2-27</td><td>40 g 6 ms, 4000 shocks each in every direction of the 3 coordinate axes</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>
<tr><td>Fast temperature changes</td><td><table><caption></caption><colgroup class='pd-table-cols-2'><col class='pd-table-col-1'><col class='pd-table-col-2'></colgroup><tbody>
<tr><td>EN 60068-2-14 Na</td><td>TA = -40 °C, TB = 85 °C, t1 = 30 min, t2 = &lt, 10 s, 50 cycles</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>
<tr><td>Salt spray test</td><td><table><caption></caption><colgroup class='pd-table-cols-2'><col class='pd-table-col-1'><col class='pd-table-col-2'></colgroup><tbody>
<tr><td>EN 60068-2-52 Kb</td><td>severity level 5 (4 test cycles)</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>
<tr><td>MTTF [years]</td><td>473</td></tr>
<tr><td>UL approval</td><td><table><caption></caption><colgroup class='pd-table-cols-2'><col class='pd-table-col-1'><col class='pd-table-col-2'></colgroup><tbody>
<tr><td>Ta</td><td>-25...70 °C</td></tr>
<tr><td>Enclosure type</td><td>Type 1 </td></tr>
<tr><td>voltage supply</td><td>Limited Voltage/Current </td></tr>
<tr><td>UL approval number</td><td>A005 </td></tr>
<tr><td>File number UL</td><td>E174191 </td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>
<tr><td>Weight [g]</td><td>23.8</td></tr>
<tr><td>Housing</td><td>Threaded type</td></tr>
<tr><td>Mounting</td><td>flush mountable</td></tr>
<tr><td>Dimensions [mm]</td><td>M12 x 1 / L = 45</td></tr>
<tr><td>Thread designation</td><td>M12 x 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Material</td><td>stainless steel (1.4404 / 316L), sensing face: LCP white, LED window: PEI, lock nuts: stainless steel (1.4404 / 316L)</td></tr>
<tr><td>Display</td><td><table><caption></caption><colgroup class='pd-table-cols-2'><col class='pd-table-col-1'><col class='pd-table-col-2'></colgroup><tbody>
<tr><td>Switching status</td><td>4 x LED, yellow</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>
<tr><td>Items supplied</td><td><table><caption></caption><colgroup class='pd-table-cols-1'><col class='pd-table-col-1'></colgroup><tbody>
<tr><td>lock nuts: 2</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>
<tr><td>Pack quantity</td><td>1 pcs.</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Specifically with respect to the html you posted,

```
//table//tr[not(.//table)]
```

should work anyway. But in other cases, this expression

```
 //table//tr[not(.//table)][not(.//tr)]
```

should exclude both.

Comment: Tr tags that are in the tbody tag are skipped :(

Comment: @MMAXX Not sure what you mean; are saying that the expression selects a `<tr>` tag that has either a `<table>` child or a `<tr>` child?

Comment: Tags tr which contains a cell with a nested table must be skipped.
//td//table//tbody//tr's
Take it - <tr><td>Electrical design</td><td>PNP</td></tr>

Skip it 
<tr><td>UL approval</td><td><table><caption></caption><colgroup class='pd-table-cols-2'><col class='pd-table-col-1'><col class='pd-table-col-2'></colgroup><tbody>
<tr><td>Ta</td><td>-25...70 °C</td></tr>
...
<tr><td>UL approval number</td><td>A005 </td></tr>

Comment: @MMAXX Not sure what the problem is; it works on my end.

Comment: [Xpather](http://xpather.com/wBB1M3zd) 
Tags tr which contains a cell with a nested table must be skipped.
Take it - <tr><td>Electrical design</td><td>PNP</td></tr>

Comment: Skip it 
<tr><td>UL approval</td><td><table><caption></caption>...<tbody>
<tr><td>Ta</td><td>-25...70 °C</td></tr>
...
<tr><td>UL approval number</td><td>A005 </td></tr>

Comment: The html in your xpather link is not well formed; that may cause the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I thought for a long time and came to this decision //table//tr[not(.//caption)][not(../following::tbody//tr)][count(td)=2]  [xpather](http://xpather.com/Qx2QWUE9)